# MS Access: Permission problems with views

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access, sql-server-2008

"I'll use an Access ADP" I said, "it's only a tiny project and I've got better things to do", I said, "I can build an interface really quickly in Access" I said.

</sarcasm>

Sorry for the rant, but it's Friday, I have a date in just under two hours, and I'm here late because this just isn't working - so, in despair, I turn to SO for help.

- Access ADP front-end, linked to a SQL Server 2008 database
- Using a SQL Server account to log into the database (for testing); this account is a member of the role, "Api"; this role has SELECT, EXECUTE, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE access to the "Api" schema
- The "Api" schema is owned by "dbo"
- All tables have a corresponding view in the Api schema: e.g. dbo.Customer --> Api.Customers
- The rationale is that users don't have direct table access, but can deal with views as if they were tables

I can log into SQL using my test login, and it works fine: no access to the tables, but I can select, insert, update and delete from the Api views.

In Access, I see the views, I can open them, but whenever I try to insert or update, I get the following error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object '[Table name which the view is using]', database '[database name]', schema 'dbo'

Crazy as it sounds, Access seems to be trying to access the underlying table rather than the view.

Any ideas?

Comment: A long shot, but is there a primary key identified to Access through the view?

Comment: ADO sometimes chooses to bypass the view permissions and attempt to apply the updates to the underlying tables. This is by design so that ADO can update data in a SQL statement that might otherwise be unupdatable (this is good), but the downside is that it doesn it sometimes when it doesn't need to do so (as is perhaps the case with your view). This is one of the many flaws of classic ADO and one of the reasons many advanced Access developers abandoned ADPs years ago. You do realize that Microsoft has been deprecating ADPs in favor of MDB/ODBC for about 5 years now, right?

Comment: @Knox: I'll have a go, and see if that makes a difference..
@David: Yes, I know how crappy ADPs are (believe me, I know); I might give MDB/ODBC a go, but if it turns into too much of a pain I might try to convince management to give me an extra couple of weeks and just build an ASP.NET front end with reporting services. Thanks for the info though - useful!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of this: "To update a partitioned view, the user must have INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions on the member tables."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx